# Drupal 7 - Node specific template not working

Tags: theming

I have done some research and everything I see to create a node specific template says to name the template file, for example, page--node--676.tpl.php

However when I clear the cache and load the file it still shows the old template. What could I be missing?

Comment: In what folder did you put page--node--676.tpl.php?

Comment: sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already done so, I'd recommend enabling theme debugging feature of Drupal 7.

In the **settings.php** file, or preferably in **settings.local.php** file if you have one, add the following line, and clear the cache once more.

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

> When debugging is enabled:
>   - The markup of each template is surrounded by HTML comments that contain
>     theming information, such as template file name suggestions.
>   - Note that this debugging markup will cause automated tests that directly
>     check rendered HTML to fail.
>
> For more information about debugging theme templates, see
>   https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#theme-debug.
>
> Not recommended in production environments.

This should give you the available template name suggestions in the generated HTML.

Comment: debugging returned the suggested 
page--node--676.tpl.php
sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates
and that is is loading page.tpl.php

Comment: Are you saying when you view `/node/676` your theme still uses `sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/page.tpl.php` instead? Or `page.tpl.php` from another theme? Do you use a base theme?

Comment: Yes, when I view /node/676 the theme is still using sites/all/themes/mytheme/template/page.tpl.php instead of page--node--676.tpl.php
the only other template source I can see is modules/system/html.tpl.php

Comment: That’s odd. Even if you have a preprocess function in your theme overwriting suggested template names, debugging would show those in results too. Any chance the file name has invisible characters in it? Try copying the suggested name and renaming your template file with that.

Comment: Not sure what I did, but it started working. Thanks for the help.